# Why is my Code returing errors when I use SMTP to try and send an email

Tags: python, smtp

Trying to run a program that will send an email, but when I run the following code, I get errors on line 8 and 13. help?

```
import smtplib
import os


email_address = os.environ.get('Email_Address')
email_password = os.environ.get('Email_Password')
receiver = os.environ.get('Other_address')
with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) as smtp:
    smtp.ehlo()
    smtp.starttls()
    smtp.ehlo()
    
    smtp.login(email_address, email_password)
    
    subject = 'hello'
    body = "hello"
    msg = f'subject: {subject}\n\n{body}'

    smtp.sendmail(email_address, receiver, msg)
```

these are the errors that i am recieving

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Finn\OneDrive\Documents\python\alex fuckery", line 13, in <module>
    smtp.login(email_address, email_password)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\smtplib.py", line 734, in login
    (code, resp) = self.auth(
  File "C:\Python310\lib\smtplib.py", line 647, in auth
    authobject(challenge).encode('ascii'), eol='')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Finn\OneDrive\Documents\python\alex fuckery", line 8, in <module>
    with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) as smtp:
  File "C:\Python310\lib\smtplib.py", line 284, in __exit__
    raise SMTPResponseException(code, message)
smtplib.SMTPResponseException: (334, b'UGFzc3dvcmQ6')
[Finished in 0.5s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "C:\Users\Finn\OneDrive\Documents\python\alex fuckery"]
[dir: C:\Users\Finn\OneDrive\Documents\python]
[path: C:\Python310\Scripts\;C:\Python310\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs;C:\Users\Finn\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.9;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Users\Finn\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;]
```

Comment: And what are the errors?

Comment: Your environment variables are not set, hence the `os.environ.get` returns `None` which you then pass to the `smtplib` which tries to encode them, but that fails because you cannot encode `None`. Check for the variables. Case matters.